# FlowLayout extending behind component in BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing

when my program resizes to a smaller window size and the FlowLayout creates new rows, the FlowLayout extends behind the JTextArea. How do I make it so that the JTextArea resizes in response to the extension of the FlowLayout?

```java
package editor;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TextEditor extends JFrame {
    public TextEditor() {
        super("Text Editor");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JTextArea TextArea = new JTextArea();
        TextArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 10, 10));
        TextArea.setName("TextArea");
        JScrollPane ScrollPane = new JScrollPane(TextArea);
        ScrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 10, 5, 10));
        add(ScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        jPanel.add(new JTextField(18));
        jPanel.add(new JButton("Save"));
        jPanel.add(new JButton("Load"));
        add(jPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider adding a screen shot of the bad behavior and using it to explain the desired behavior.  But in general flow layout only makes sense if the widgets it's managing have a fixed size.  You may need to switch to a different layout type.

Comment: You probably need to define the minimum size - having said that, that's no easy task

Comment: *How do I make it so that the JTextArea resizes in response to the extension of the FlowLayout?* - Actually you do it the other way around. When the components wrap you need to reset the preferred size of the panel, not the text area. Then the `BorderLayout` will respect the height of the top panel and reset the size of the scroll pane. See: [Wrap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) which does this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Original Answer

You have to get the basics correct before you can tackle the advanced problems.  I fixed your GUI code.

[image: Text Editor]

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

When creating a `JFrame`, you pack the `JFrame` and set the `JFrame` visible last.  You do not set the size of the `JFrame`.  The `JFrame` will size based on the components you're displaying.

I added row and column counts to your `JTextArea`.  This allows the BorderLayout to size itself properly.

If you want the `JButtons` to display under the `JTextArea`, you have to use a different Swing layout.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TextEditorExample extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TextEditorExample();
            }
        });
    }

    public TextEditorExample() {
        super("Text Editor");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);
        textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 10, 10));
        textArea.setName("TextArea");
        JScrollPane ScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        ScrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 10, 5, 10));
        add(ScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        jPanel.add(new JTextField(18));
        jPanel.add(new JButton("Save"));
        jPanel.add(new JButton("Load"));
        add(jPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

## Extended Answer

In order to resize the control panel properly, you have to use a [ComponentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) (`ComponentAdapter`).

Here's the original GUI:

[image: Original GUI]

Here's the shrunk GUI:

[image: Shrunk GUI]

Here's the expanded GUI:

[image]

In the `ComponentListener`, I save the original size of the control `JPanel`.  When the control `JPanel` width is less than the original width, I double the height.  When the control `JPanel` width is greater than or equal to the original width, I use the original height.

I invalidate the `JFrame` to get it to recalculate the GUI.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TextEditorExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TextEditorExample());        
    }
    
    private Dimension controlPanelDimension;
    
    private JFrame frame;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Text Editor");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createControlPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(createTextArea(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createControlPanel() {
        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        jPanel.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            boolean firstTimeSwitch = true;
            
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent event) {
                if (firstTimeSwitch) {
                    controlPanelDimension = jPanel.getPreferredSize();
                    firstTimeSwitch = false;
                }
                
                Dimension d = jPanel.getSize();
                if (d.width < controlPanelDimension.width) {
                    int height = 2 * controlPanelDimension.height;
                    jPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(d.width, height));
                } else {
                    int height = controlPanelDimension.height;
                    jPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(d.width, height));    
                }
                frame.invalidate();
            }   
        });
        
        jPanel.add(new JTextField(18));
        jPanel.add(new JButton("Save"));
        jPanel.add(new JButton("Load"));
        
        return jPanel;
    }
    
    private JScrollPane createTextArea() {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);
        textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 10, 10));

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 10, 5, 10));
        
        return scrollPane;
    }

}
```

Comment: *I fixed your GUI code.* - but it doesn't solve the stated problem.

Comment: @camickr: It does now.

Comment: Still doesn't work if you decrease the width so that the components are on 3 lines. Hardcoding the height is not a good idea. Just use your original code and replaces the FlowLayout with the `WrapLayout` (I suggested in my comment to the question) and let the layout manager do the job.

Comment: Check out this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75772847/jpanel-flicking-when-component-resized, which also tries to use a ComponentListener to manipulate the preferred size of a component: .  A different problem but the solution in both cases is to not use a ComponentListener to try to implement layout management logic.

Answer (score -1):

Please make variables look like variables and not like classes:

```
    JTextArea TextArea = new JTextArea();
    TextArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 10, 10));
    TextArea.setName("TextArea");
    JScrollPane ScrollPane = new JScrollPane(TextArea);
```

This:

```
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 10, 10));
    textArea.setName("TextArea");
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
```

So, to your question . .

When adding a `JScrollPane`, it has to know the size of your `JTextArea`, i.e. `setMinimumSize` as opposed to `setPreferredSize`.

The it can then position your `JTextArea` correctly.

You also have to understand the differences between the Java layout managers.

Comment: (1-) The preferred size is the relevant size when using a scroll panel. The scrollbars will appear when the preferred size of the component added is greater than the size of the scroll pane. Also, you should NOT be using setPreferredSize. It is the job of each component to determine its preferred size.