# JPanel flicking when component resized

Tags: java, swing, awt

First of all, I want to clarify that I am aware that this has been asked many times. However, I haven't found an answer that has worked for me.

I'm trying to make a game in which resolution is needed. So I got to work and made one component adapt to the size of another while maintaining the aspect ratio.

But I ran into a problem, and that is that a kind of flick or a resize of the object occurs particularly when the JFrame is made smaller.

In addition to investigating, I checked that the scale gave numbers that made sense and I did not detect anything unusual. I also tried to activate double buffering (despite knowing that it is enabled by default in JPanels) and nothing....

I've written similar code below so you can see and test what's going on. What is the mistake?

```
package novely;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestApp extends JFrame{
    private JPanel panel; 
    private JPanel container;
    
    public TestApp() {
        setSize(800, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        this.container = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        
        this.panel = new JPanel();
        this.panel.setBackground(Color.black);
        
        this.container.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {

            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                int reswidth = 800;
                int resheight = 600;
                Dimension parent_size = container.getSize();
                
                double scale = Math.min((double) parent_size.height / resheight,
                                        (double) parent_size.width / reswidth);
                
                panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) (reswidth * scale), (int) (resheight * scale)));
                panel.revalidate();
            }

            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            }

            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            }

            @Override
            public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            }
            
        });
        
        this.container.add(this.panel);
        
        add(this.container);
    }
    
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        TestApp app = new TestApp();
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to add layout management logic in the ComponentListener.

Yes, the ComponentListener sets the preferred size, but the `getPreferredSize()` method can be called on the panel by Swing separately when required. The default getPreferredSize() logic will return a size of (10, 10) so you see a small rectangle painted for a brief moment.

The solution is to move the preferred size logic to the component:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestApp extends JFrame{
    private JPanel panel;
    private JPanel container;

    public TestApp() {
        setSize(800, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.container = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        this.panel = new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize()
            {
                int reswidth = 800;
                int resheight = 600;
                Dimension parent_size = container.getSize();

                double scale = Math.min((double) parent_size.height / resheight,
                                        (double) parent_size.width / reswidth);

                return new Dimension((int) (reswidth * scale), (int) (resheight * scale));

            }
        };
        this.panel.setBackground(Color.black);

        this.container.add(this.panel);

        add(this.container);
    }

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        TestApp app = new TestApp();
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```