# How to add and remove scrollbars dynamically to a zoomable panel based on Rectangle's visibility

Tags: java, swing, zooming, jscrollpane, mousewheel

I am trying to manipulate some blue rectangles within a confined, much larger red rectangle.
I have this working along with a zoom-in and zoom-out function

The problem is I would like to display scrollbars whenever the red rectangle is not completely visible
and dynamically remove the scrollbars when the entire red rectangle is visible.

How can i achieve this? This is what i got so far...

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Zoomable Canvas");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);

        ZoomPanel zoomPanel = new ZoomPanel();
        frame.add(zoomPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}

class ZoomPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private double zoomFactor = 1.0;
    private static final double ZOOM_MULTIPLIER = 1.1;
    private static final double MIN_ZOOM = 0.1; // Minimum zoom level
    private static final double MAX_ZOOM = 4.0; // Maximum zoom level

    private Point zoomCenter;
    private AffineTransform currentTransform;
    private Point lastMousePosition;
    private Rectangle2D.Double square;
    private Point dragOffset;
    private Rectangle2D.Double redRectangle;

    public ZoomPanel() {
        currentTransform = new AffineTransform();
        square = new Rectangle2D.Double(100, 100, 200, 200);
        redRectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

        addMouseWheelListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
                double adjustedZoomFactor = e.getWheelRotation() < 0 ? ZOOM_MULTIPLIER : 1 / ZOOM_MULTIPLIER;
                double newZoomFactor = zoomFactor * adjustedZoomFactor;

                // Check if the new zoom factor is within the valid range
                if (newZoomFactor >= MIN_ZOOM && newZoomFactor <= MAX_ZOOM) {
                    zoomFactor = newZoomFactor;
                    zoomCenter = e.getPoint();

                    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
                    at.translate(zoomCenter.getX(), zoomCenter.getY());
                    at.scale(adjustedZoomFactor, adjustedZoomFactor);
                    at.translate(-zoomCenter.getX(), -zoomCenter.getY());

                    currentTransform.preConcatenate(at);

                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                Point transformedPoint = transformPoint(e.getPoint(), currentTransform);
                if (square.contains(transformedPoint)) {
                    lastMousePosition = e.getPoint();
                    dragOffset = new Point(transformedPoint.x - (int) square.getX(), transformedPoint.y - (int) square.getY());
                } else {
                    lastMousePosition = null;
                }
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                if (lastMousePosition != null) {
                    Point transformedPoint = transformPoint(e.getPoint(), currentTransform);
                    int newX = transformedPoint.x - dragOffset.x;
                    int newY = transformedPoint.y - dragOffset.y;

                    // Check if the new position is within the red rectangle
                    if (redRectangle.contains(newX, newY, square.getWidth(), square.getHeight())) {
                        square.setRect(newX, newY, square.getWidth(), square.getHeight());
                        lastMousePosition = e.getPoint();

                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            }
          });
      }
    
    
    private Point transformPoint(Point point, AffineTransform transform) {
        try {
            AffineTransform inverse = transform.createInverse();
            Point transformedPoint = new Point();
            inverse.transform(point, transformedPoint);
            return transformedPoint;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // Apply zoom factor
        if (zoomCenter != null) {
            g2d.transform(currentTransform);
        }

        // Draw red rectangle
        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
        g2d.fill(redRectangle);

        // Draw blue square
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.fill(square);
    }
}
```

The code I have is buggy ...

```
package zoom;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Zoomable Canvas");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);

        ZoomPanel zoomPanel = new ZoomPanel();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(zoomPanel);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}

class ZoomPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private double zoomFactor = 1.0;
    private static final double ZOOM_MULTIPLIER = 1.1;
    private static final double MIN_ZOOM = 0.1; // Minimum zoom level
    private static final double MAX_ZOOM = 4.0; // Maximum zoom level

    private Point zoomCenter;
    private AffineTransform currentTransform;
    private Point lastMousePosition;
    private Rectangle2D.Double square;
    private Point dragOffset;
    private Rectangle2D.Double redRectangle;

    public ZoomPanel() {
        currentTransform = new AffineTransform();
        square = new Rectangle2D.Double(100, 100, 200, 200);
        redRectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

        addMouseWheelListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
                double adjustedZoomFactor = e.getWheelRotation() < 0 ? ZOOM_MULTIPLIER : 1 / ZOOM_MULTIPLIER;
                double newZoomFactor = zoomFactor * adjustedZoomFactor;

                // Check if the new zoom factor is within the valid range
                if (newZoomFactor >= MIN_ZOOM && newZoomFactor <= MAX_ZOOM) {
                    zoomFactor = newZoomFactor;
                    zoomCenter = e.getPoint();

                    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
                    at.translate(zoomCenter.getX(), zoomCenter.getY());
                    at.scale(adjustedZoomFactor, adjustedZoomFactor);
                    at.translate(-zoomCenter.getX(), -zoomCenter.getY());

                    currentTransform.preConcatenate(at);
                    updatePreferredSize(); // Add this line
                    repaint();
                }
            
            }
        });

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                Point transformedPoint = transformPoint(e.getPoint(), currentTransform);
                if (square.contains(transformedPoint)) {
                    lastMousePosition = e.getPoint();
                    dragOffset = new Point(transformedPoint.x - (int) square.getX(), transformedPoint.y - (int) square.getY());
                } else {
                    lastMousePosition = null;
                }
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                if (lastMousePosition != null) {
                    Point transformedPoint = transformPoint(e.getPoint(), currentTransform);
                    int newX = transformedPoint.x - dragOffset.x;
                    int newY = transformedPoint.y - dragOffset.y;

                    // Check if the new position is within the red rectangle
                    if (redRectangle.contains(newX, newY, square.getWidth(), square.getHeight())) {
                        square.setRect(newX, newY, square.getWidth(), square.getHeight());
                        lastMousePosition = e.getPoint();

                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            }
          });
      }
    
    
    private Point transformPoint(Point point, AffineTransform transform) {
        try {
            AffineTransform inverse = transform.createInverse();
            Point transformedPoint = new Point();
            inverse.transform(point, transformedPoint);
            return transformedPoint;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // Apply zoom factor
        if (zoomCenter != null) {
            g2d.transform(currentTransform);
        }

        // Draw red rectangle
        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
        g2d.fill(redRectangle);

        // Draw blue square
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.fill(square);
    }

    private void updateScrollbars() {
        Container parent = getParent();
        if (parent instanceof JViewport) {
            JViewport viewport = (JViewport) parent;
            Rectangle viewRect = viewport.getViewRect();

            boolean horizontalScrollbarVisible = viewRect.width < redRectangle.width * zoomFactor;
            boolean verticalScrollbarVisible = viewRect.height < redRectangle.height * zoomFactor;

            JScrollPane scrollPane = (JScrollPane) SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JScrollPane.class, this);
            if (scrollPane != null) {
                scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(horizontalScrollbarVisible ? JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED : JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
                scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(verticalScrollbarVisible ? JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED : JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            }
        }
    }

    private void updatePreferredSize() {
        int width = (int) (redRectangle.width * zoomFactor);
        int height = (int) (redRectangle.height * zoomFactor);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        revalidate();
    }
    
}
```

I tried camickr's advice and didn't use the scrollbarpolicy and override getPreferredSize which works -- sort of..i get funky scrollbars flashing when i resize and whatever i try, i cannot capture the restore event after a maximize...so the override code doesn't have any effect

```
package zoom;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SwingApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing App");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setResizable(true);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        Editor editor = new Editor(scrollPane);

/*
        frame.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
                if ((e.getNewState() & Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) == Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH
                        || e.getNewState() == Frame.NORMAL) {
                    editor.updateWorkspace();
                    editor.updatePreferredSize();
                    frame.repaint();
                }
            }
        });
*/
        frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
            @Override public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {               
                editor.updateWorkspace();
                editor.updatePreferredSize();
                editor.repaint();
            }
            @Override public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent arg0) {}
            @Override public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent arg0) {}
            @Override public void componentShown(ComponentEvent arg0) {}                
        });     

        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class Editor extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private static final int WORKSPACE_WIDTH = 300;
        private static final int WORKSPACE_HEIGHT = 300;

        private Dimension preferredSize;
        private Rectangle workspace;
        private Rectangle box;
        private JScrollPane scrollPane;

        private Editor(JScrollPane s) {
            scrollPane = s;
            preferredSize = new Dimension(WORKSPACE_WIDTH, WORKSPACE_HEIGHT);
            workspace = new Rectangle(0, 0, WORKSPACE_WIDTH, WORKSPACE_HEIGHT);
            box = new Rectangle(workspace.x + 100, workspace.y + 100, 100, 100);
            scrollPane.setViewportView(this);
//          updateWorkspace();
//          updatePreferredSize();
//          revalidate();
        }

        public void updateWorkspace() {
            int xPos = (getWidth() - workspace.width) / 2;
            int yPos = (getHeight() - workspace.height) / 2;
            workspace = new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, workspace.width, workspace.height);
            box = new Rectangle(workspace.x + 100, workspace.y + 100, box.width, box.height);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return preferredSize;
        }

        private void updatePreferredSize() {
            Rectangle v = scrollPane.getViewport().getVisibleRect();

            if(v != null) { 
                int left = Math.min(v.x, workspace.x);
                int right = Math.max(v.x + v.width, workspace.x + workspace.width);
                int top = Math.min(v.y, workspace.y);
                int bottom = Math.max(v.y + v.height, workspace.y + workspace.height);
                preferredSize = new Dimension(right-left, bottom-top);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect(workspace.x, workspace.y, workspace.width, workspace.height);

            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRect(box.x, box.y, box.width, box.height);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with using a JScrollPane? Anyway, please add code of what you tried to achieve your requirement

Comment: i added it, but it makes the code more messy

Comment: *The code I have is buggy ...* - 1) don't play with the scrollbar policy. When the scroll pane is used correctly the scrollbars will appear/disappear as required. 2) Also, don't use the setPreferredSize() method. It is the job of each component to determine its own preferred size. Instead you should override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your component. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75772987/131872 for a basic solution to a similar problem.

Comment: ok, removed the policy and override getPreferreSize as you suggest, but seethe scrollbars flashing and unable to capture restore events (see code above)

Answer (score 0):

ScrollbarPolicies helps to configure the visibility of the scrollbars in the JScrollPane. You can set to show up as needed with these:
scrollpane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);       scrollpane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

The default value, if I'm not mistaken is the ALWAYS constant, and it can be set up to NEVER if needed.

Here is the oracle documentation of the usage for scrollpanes:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#setup

Comment: This looks like a question and a link. Neither separatly nor combined that is an answer. Please read [answer] and take the [tour]. Then [edit] to give more of a solution directly here and preferrably more assertively.

Comment: It didn't look that way when I wrote that up, thank you.